# matplotlib.pyplot plot gives multiple dots plotted in the same coordinates. How to show how many dots are at each coordinate?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[The graph obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70elL.png)

```
plt.xlabel('Half Time Result')
plt.ylabel('Full Time Result')
plt.scatter(htr, ftr, marker='.', color='black')
plt.savefig('htrvsftr')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add some random jitter, for example by adding a small gaussian random value to each coordinate:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

htr = np.random.randint(1, 9, 500)
ftr = np.random.randint(1, 6, 500)

plt.xlabel('Half Time Result')
plt.ylabel('Full Time Result')
plt.scatter(htr + np.random.normal(0, .1, htr.size), ftr + np.random.normal(0, .1, ftr.size),
            marker='.', color='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Instead of `np.random.normal(0, .1)` also a uniform distribution could be used, e.g. `np.random.uniform(-.4, .4)`. If there are many more coinciding points, additionally an `alpha` value could be set.

To better visualize the differences, a 2D histogram could be drawn, for example via [seaborn's jointplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).

When the x and y values are of string type, you can extract the offset positions from the scatter plot, add the random jitter and update the positions:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

htr = np.random.choice(['H', 'D', 'A'], 500)
ftr = np.random.choice(['H', 'D', 'A'], 500)
scatter_dots = plt.scatter(htr, ftr, marker='.', color='black', alpha=0.3)

xy = scatter_dots.get_offsets()
scatter_dots.set_offsets(xy + np.random.normal(0, .1, size=xy.shape))
plt.xlabel('Half Time Result')
plt.ylabel('Full Time Result')
plt.xlim(-0.5, 2.5)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 2.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: example with categorical axes]

A seaborn `jointplot` could look like:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.jointplot(x=htr, y=ftr, kind="hist",
              joint_kws={'bins': (np.arange(-0.5, 3), np.arange(-0.5, 3))},
              marginal_kws={'lw': 1})
```

[image: jointplot example]

Comment: This would help with graphs having integer axes. But my graph only has three values on each axis and those are "H", "D" and "A".

Comment: Apply the random noise to a new column in the dataframe, and then plot that instead of the original data.